Go convert slice of type definitions to slice of underlying type
I have a function that takes a single any argument and I need to inspect it to handle various types differently. If the type is a "standard" built-in type, then the argument gets returned as is, but other custom types get cast into a type that I can handle.
I am supporting type definitions by using reflection to get the underlying type like so:
func getType(arg any) any {
  ret := arg
  switch ret.(type) {
    case string, int, int32, []string, []int32, etc....:
      // do nothing, ret is returned unmodified
    default:
      rv := reflect.ValueOf(arg)
      switch rv.Kind() {
      case reflect.String:
        ret = rv.String()
      case reflect.Int, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        ret = rv.Int()
      case reflect.Slice:
        // here is where I want to support slices of type definitions, but I can't figure out
        // how to get the first element of the slice and recursively pass it to my getType function to get the base native type
      }
  }
  return ret
}

This works great when doing something like:
type customStr string

var myStr customStr = "Hello World"
arg := getType(myStr)

But how do I support slices of arbitrary types in my getType function? I know I need to recursively call getType if the arg is a slice with the first element in the slice, and if that first element resolves to a native string then I'm going to basically for _, a := range arg { ret = append(ret, str(a)) }
But I keep getting lost in getting the slice from the reflected value and trying to index the first element.
What I want to do eventually:
val := getType([]customStr{"Hello", "World"}) // Should make val a slice of native strings


"that first element" - and what if the input slice is empty?

you can look at rv.Type() and rv.Type().Elem()

FXI: "types get cast" there are no type casts in Go.

I'm mostly getting strong X-Y problem vibes from this. What are you doing to end up in a situation where a single function is expected to literally handle any argument type, whether it be an int, a slice, a map, a pointer to any and all of the aforementioned types? Your function also accepts your own types, so you'll need to handle those, too. This just reads like "What kind of shovel should I use to dig deeper", asked by someone who dug a tunnel under the foundations of their own house. The answer is: stop digging

Finn Bear, oh no, I might have to check len!

You could do (Go Playground):
        switch rv.Kind() {
        case reflect.Slice:
            switch rv.Type().Elem().Kind() {
            case reflect.String:
                ret := make([]string, rv.Len())
                for i := range rv.Len() {
                    ret[i] = rv.Index(i).String()
                }

                return ret
            }
        }
    }

or similar. Not sure whether it's worth the effort, though.

Thank you, this is what I was looking for.
